# How to set set a HystrixProperty to a Feign request with spring cloud?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign

According to the documentation, when using Feign with Hystrix every request is wrap into a Hystrix command.

Is it possible to set Hystrix Properties to these commands? I'd like to do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(commandProperties = {
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "30000")})
List<Team> findAll();
```

or:

```
@FeignClient(name = "teams", commandProperties = {
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "30000")})
```

For the records, I've already tried to use properties but it didn't work. These ones are working:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=10000
hystrix.command.findAll.execution.timeout.enabled=false
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
```

But this one does not:

```
hystri‌​x.command.findAll.ex‌​ecution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMillis‌​econds=20000
```

Indeed, we can read the following comment into the `HystrixCommandProperties` class:

```
    //this property name is now misleading.  //TODO figure out a good way to deprecate this property name
    this.executionTimeoutInMilliseconds = getProperty(propertyPrefix, key, "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", builder.getExecutionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds(), default_executionTimeoutInMilliseconds);
```

**EDIT:** I have tried to use the feign' Request.Option but these properties doesn't seem to propagate to hystrix.

Comment: Bases on the properties you are trying to set, I assume you are trying to deal with some request timeouts, do you have the stack trace?  Is Ribbon involved?

Comment: The remote service is a bit long to respond, so I get a HystrixRuntimeException exception.

Comment: Have you only set the properties in `application.properties`?

Comment: That's what I did

Comment: `@HystrixProperty` only works with `@HystrixCommand`, not `@RequestMapping` and `@FeignClient`. Generally setting hystrix properties in `application.properties` works. Your missing `hystrix.command.<command>` prefix sometimes. Maybe you have a sample project or can put more code in the question?

Comment: I'll post some code, but I've encountered this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413777/spring-boot-1-4-0-rest-controllers-dont-set-reason-to-http-response

Comment: I think I'm encountering the same problem. `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=10000` works but `hystrix.command.myFeignMethod.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=10000` does not. Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I've forgotten to close this. Actually, it was an encoding issue: I copied/pasted a line from the documentation, but it wasn't UTF-8 encoded (although STS' display was correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: it was an encoding issue. I had copied/pasted a line from the documentation, but it wasn't UTF-8 encoded (although STS' display was correct).

Comment: in my case hystrix.command.myFeignMethod.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds= some value is not being picked, dont think its a encoding issue as properties are clearly visibile on hitting cloud config server

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1864 mentions the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the properties programatically like below.

```
ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance()
        .setProperty("hystri‌​x.command.default.ex‌​ecution.isolation.th‌​read.timeoutInMillis‌​econds", 1500);
```