# Spring Boot 1.4.0 : REST Controllers don't set reason to HTTP response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have 2 projects created with Spring Tool Suite "Spring Starter Project":

**First project :** Spring Boot 1.3.7 (Release) + Web

**Second project :** Spring Boot 1.4.0 (Release) + Web

I replace the `@SpringBootApplication` class of each project with this code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class TestWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

When I call `GET /hello` on each server I get the following responses:

**First project (1.3.7) :** Status 200 *(no reason)*

**Second project (1.4.0) :** Status 200 OK

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Besides, I can't set a reason to the 1.4.0 project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The change in behaviour is due to Spring Boot 1.4 using Tomcat 8.5 and Spring Boot 1.3 using Tomcat 8.0. Tomcat 8.5 doesn't send a reason phrase.

Strictly speaking, the reason phrase isn't required. In [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) the reason phrase is defined as:

```
reason-phrase  = *( HTAB / SP / VCHAR / ons-text )
```

Where `*` means zero or more. In other words it's legal for the reason phrase to be empty.

Tomcat 8.5 takes advantage of this and saves some bandwidth by dropping the reason phrase. If this is causing a problem for your client, then it arguably isn't spec compliant as the section of the RFC linked to above has this to say:

> The reason-phrase element exists for the sole purpose of providing a textual description associated with the numeric status code, mostly out of deference to earlier Internet application protocols that were
> more frequently used with interactive text clients.  A client SHOULD
> ignore the reason-phrase content.

You haven't said if the absence of the reason phrase is causing a problem. If it's not, then your best course of action is not to worry about it and to move on. If you really want to keep the reason phrase for some reason then switching to Undertow or Jetty is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for this response. Actually, it is a problem with Spring cloud: Feign doesn't work if the remote server respond with no reason. There's this kind of code: if (code == null || reason == null) { throw....

Comment: It has been fixed in open Feign 5 month ago: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/commit/3378eee852db21b8d08ebcf3759eb3ad37dc7264 . Not yet released apparently

Answer (score 1):

I had raised a bug with feign and it was fixed almost immediately.. 
Please check https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/382

Thanks,
KK

Comment: I hadn't seen tout réponse, but thanks. I've indeed found the commit.

Answer (score 1):

Initially the reason phrase was removed by **Tomcat-8.5**.
However, later a patch was provided to configure it with an attribute in the **Http Connector**.

All you have to do is set `sendReasonPhrase="true"`  attribute and it will work as before.

---

Use any of the below method to configure :

**Method-1 :** Update the *.../apache-tomcat-8.5.x/conf/server.xml* to include the attribute as below :

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" sendReasonPhrase="true" />
```

**Method-2 :** Configure through bean. (add in the config file)

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector ->
            ((AbstractProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setSendReasonPhrase(true));
    return factory;
}
```

---

**NOTE :**  This config will be dropped in **Tomcat-9.0.x** (ie : response message will not be sent)

**Refs :**

- [Bug Report & Discussion](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6036)
- [Tomcat documentation for configuring the attribute](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)